# Custom local hostname for a SSH tunnel

Tags: tunnel, tunneling, ssh-tunnel

Usually when a tunnel is created it begins at some port on localhost. So the local applications may use it by opening this local port.

Is it possible to use a custom name instead of the "localhost"? It should be a virtual host without any underlying virtual machines.

I need to create two tunnels (to two different computers) that begin on the same port. I thought, may be it is possible using different hostnames...

Answer (score 0):

You can setup aliases for 127.0.0.1 (=localhost) in `/etc/hosts`, **but** this won't help you. Since it's the same IP endpoint, no two applications (or tunnels, for that matter) can use the same port.

You should try to configure the client application accessing the tunnel to use a different port.

Comment: I cannot configure the client application. It should work with two servers and servers must use same port...

Answer (score 0):

You can open two tunnels on two *interfaces* (each with their own corresponding IP) using the same port. If you have names mapped to these IPs then you will get your desired result but it will require multiple interfaces (e.g. multiple network cards).

Remember name mapping is performed on the calling computer before making a connection and the IP address is used to identify the machine, not the name.

(It could be that SSH has multiple tunnel from same listening port support but I am not aware of it if it has.)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any tool that combines both: virtual NIC and SSH tunneling?

Comment: You could try setting up a VPN over SSH, perhaps. Out of my area of expertise I am afraid.